# No repository found error when revert sts configuration

Tags: eclipse, spring, ide, spring-tool-suite

I really should research first before Just simply updating my sts.

I updated my sts from 3.6.1 to 3.7.0 several days ago.

Now it gives me many trouble.

I want to revert the configuration back to 3.6.1, but it keeps failing me and giving me No repository found error.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
    session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
    No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature,3.6.1.201408250705-RELEASE
    No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.sts.package,3.6.1.201408250818-RELEASE-e44
```

what should I do? is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been played with my ide for 2 days, I'm not sure if I could revert now.

but now my ide works fine for me.

what I did is manually switch workplace to one of my saved workplace.

I guess the ide is pointing to some other workplace after update. As a result, it mess up some settings or jre enviroments.

hope this could help some ones who has the same problem